# Change file associations for all users

Tags: windows, windows-registry, file-associations, autoit

I have to configure a bunch of computers with Windows XP and im trying to create a script with Autoit so make my work easier. The issue is the following:

I want to make certain extensions to open with a determinate software **FOR ALL USERS** in the system. (For example, open all .PSD files with XnView). I figure the best way to do this is to manipulate the register, but Im not sure how to do this task.

Can someone please how to achieve this goal?

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best solution: Setting File Extension Default Program through GPO

Comment: Group Policy is a feature of the Microsoft in Active Directory environment. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb310732

Comment: if you have peer-to-peer LAN it is impossible by GPO. You should have Windows Server at LAN and Active Directory.